# Perl regex: replace all \n to "|", Except a \n followed by some static text(abc)

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a file f1.txt which contains below text

```
abc
123
456
abc
456
343
abc
asd
23d
```

I want output of my regex to be

Every `abc` should start with new line, with all else (should be separated by | symbol) up to the next `abc` on it

```
abc|123|456
abc|456|343
abc|asd|23d
```

I tried below regex which is not producing expected result.

```
perl -p -e 's/\n(?!abc)/|/g' f1.txt
```

What will be the correct regex?, what i am missing? Thanks

Comment: Can you state the requirement in words?  (Is it that every `abc` should start a new line, with all else up to the next one on it?)

Comment: yes, every `abc` should start with new line, with all else (should be separated by | symbol) up to the next one on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `perl` command in slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(\S+)\R(?!abc\R|\z)/$1|/g' file
```

```
abc|123|456
abc|456|343
abc|asd|23d
```

or else:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(\S+)\K\R(?!abc\R|\z)/|/g' file
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace character
- `\R`: Match a line break
- `(?!abc\R|\z)`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have `abc` followed by line break OR end of file ahead

**Replacement**

- `/$1|`: Put captured value in group #1 back with `|`

---

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '{printf "%s", ($1 ~ /^abc/ ? (NR>1?"\n":"") : "|") $0} END{print ""}' file
```

Comment: Can we able to implement this without `slurp mode`, because we have large size file

Comment: Would you consider `awk` solution?

Comment: Yes,In awk how to create condition from `$1 == "abc"` to `line starts with "abc" `,meaning we might have `abc` line with extra text in same line like this `abc line having extra text`. Again Thank u very much for support

Comment: For what it's worth, Perl can do what awk can do. Do the same thing in Perl and you don't need the fancy regex.

Comment: @anubhava How to pass "abc" through shell variable in above awk command

Comment: @Nasrudeen: You can use: `awk -v s="$var" '{printf "%s", ($1 ~ "^" s ? (NR>1?"\n":"") : "|") $0} END{print ""}' file`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex or to slurp the entire file. If you instead think about what you have to output before each element instead of after each element, you don't have to lookahead. You are outputting a pipe character before every element unless that element is the magic string. When you see that magic string, you output a newline before it. You only ever need to know the current element to know what you need to do. The only time you don't output a prefix is the first line.

Here's a one-liner that will do the job. This reads each line and removes the newline with `chomp`, so that part of the problem is solved. Next, it figures out what should be in front of the thing it's about to output.  It precedes the element with a `|` if the string is not the first column magic text, and a newline otherwise (except if it's the first line you've read):

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp; print $_ eq q(abc) ? ($.==1 ? q() : qq(\n) ) . $_ : qq(|$_)' in.txt
```

The embedded conditional operator is a bit messy, and is essentially this program:

```perl
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    print do {
        if( $_ eq 'abc' ) {
            if( $. == 1 ) { $_ }
            else { "\n$_" }
            }
        else { "|$_" }
        }
    }
```